# get value from an atypical json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have two different json arrays to concat.

```
var json_1 = [{
  acceleration: 15,
  cylinders:    4,
  displacement: 98,
  horsepower:   80,
  id:           90,
  model_year:   72,
  mpg:          28,
  name:         "dodge colt (sw)",
  origin:       1,
  weight:       2164
}, {
  acceleration: 14,
  cylinders:    8,
  displacement: 307,
  horsepower:   130,
  id:           80,
  model_year:   72,
  mpg:          13,
  name:         "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)",
  origin:       1,
  weight:       4098
}];


var json_2 = [{
  color:  'name',
  number: "id",
  x:      "cylinders",
  y:      "horsepower"
}];
```

Next I do concat json_1 and json_2.

```
    $.concat||$.extend({concat:function(b,c){var a=[];
    for(x in arguments)a=a.concat(arguments[x]);return a;}});

var data = $.concat(json_1, json_2);
```

Now it is very interesting. I want to use value of key from json_2 that  to have value from data.
First I define varisble a color

```
var color =  data[data.length - 1].color;
```

And as result I can see

```
console.log("RESULT!!!! value from color is name", data.map(function(d) {
  return d[color];
})); // solution ["dodge colt (sw)", "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"]
```

My question is, how to write `var color =  data[data.length - 1].color;` more clever to get a solution  `["dodge colt (sw)", "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"]`

[Here is my DEMO :)](http://jsfiddle.net/toshkaexe/aqkEw/)

Comment: Why are you concatenating the two arrays together? (By the way, there's no JSON shown in your question. What you have is arrays of objects. JSON is always a string.)

Comment: as i understand you don't need `concat` rather you need `map`

Comment: yes, I have arrays of  objects. I am concatenating, because I transmit this array to function.
My question is, how to write var color = data[data.length - 1].color; more clever to get a solution ["dodge colt (sw)", "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"]

Comment: @user2902946 json_2 may have a length greater than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse your JSON string.

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(''); // Insert your JSON string
var color = jsonObj.color;
```

Comment: OP doesn't have a JSON string. At least, there's no JSON shown in the question.

Comment: My question is, how to write `var color =  data[data.length - 1].color;` more clever to get a solution  `["dodge colt (sw)", "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need `concat` and will be better if you use some object like this

```
var obj = {data:json_1, aliases:json_2[0]}
```

and than

```
var color = obj.aliases.color;
obj.data.map(function(d) {
    return d[color];
}) // solution ["dodge colt (sw)", "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"]
```

but if you still want to use `concat` you can do somthing like this

```
data.map(function(d) {
    return d[color];
}).filter(function(_){return _ !== undefined})); // solution ["dodge colt (sw)", "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"]
```

or

```
data.slice(0,data.length-1).map(function(d) {
    return d[color];
}) // solution ["dodge colt (sw)", "chevrolet chevelle concours (sw)"]
```